# Ubuntu 14.04 runs too slow

Tags: 14.04

After a blackout, my pc with ubuntu 14.04 LTS runs too slow. Booting was slow, login screen loading takes a lot of time and in the desktop screen too. Opening an app takes more time, then it is faded in black. Hardware is not under the minimum required.

What could be the reason and how to solve it?

I've tried error checking the disk using `fsck`

But it didn't help. Is reinstalling is the only way?

Answer (score 0):

BY blackout I guess you mean Power Outage?
Just to be sure
From a terminal do

```
sudo touch /forcefsc
```

then reboot

Comment: yes. and it helps a bit. now its working fine but not good as the previous state.

Comment: That's a little subjective. Be more specific

Comment: Ok. The app windows hangs a sec, booting is little bit faster but not the normal speed. Still hangs. When I clicked on app, it takes nearly 1 minute to open the app.